# Ethereum wallet and private key

Tags: solidity, contract-design, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, myetherwallet

how to generate public and private key for each user on my decentralized app?
After filling the app on ethereum network?

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  I think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

please see

[Is there API to create Ether wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/is-there-api-to-create-ether-wallet)

someone else is looking for the same solution. Although I will say that users of ur d-app may not be happy with your generating a key pair through your protocol/network as they are trusting a third-party and this effects the trustless-ness nature of decentralised applications

Comment: i want to know if this will help to create both private key and public key for each user on the app. and more so what are the input required by ethereumfrom each user to generate wallet for them?